# String.prototype causing loop to exit early

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have defined a method of String.prototype called `clean`

```
String.prototype.clean = function() {       
        clean = new Array();
        tokens = [
            ['&', '&amp;'],
            ['"', '&quot;'],
            ["'", '&#039;'],
            ['<', '&lt;'],
            ['>', '&gt;']
        ];
        for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {      
            s = this[i];

            for(a = 0; a < tokens.length; a++) {
                if(tokens[a][0] == s) {
                    s = tokens[a][1];
                    break;
                }
            }

            clean.push(s);          

        }

        str =  clean.join("");
        return str;
    }
```

It seems to work when called in a loop, like this:

```
str = ["<script>", "<", ">"];
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log(str[i].clean());
    }
```

The for loop breaks after the first call to `clean()` and the console looks like this:

```
[2/20/2014 8:19:26 PM] &lt;script&gt;
```

Why is this happening, and what am I doing wrong here?

Output excepted:

```
&lt;script&gt;
&lt;
&gt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
str = ["<script>", "<", ">"];
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(str[i].clean());
}
```

which creates a global variable *i* when executed. You then have:

```
String.prototype.clean = function() {     
    ...
    for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {      
    ...
}
```

which modifies the value of the global *i*. Always keep variables in an appropriate context by declaring with *var*, e.g.:

```
for (var i = 0; ...; ...) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very fast way to do the same:

```
var __entityMap = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#39;',
    "/": '&#x2F;'
};

String.prototype.toHtml = function() {
    return String(this).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {  
        return __entityMap[s];
    });
}
```

I have yet to find a quicker way....

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question though.

Comment: I know... really busy right now to dive into the code...just wanted to  share this as I found it on SO.

Comment: It is very fast compared to the best alternative I can think if at the moment, however it would be interesting to see how it goes if the full list of about [250 entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) is used.

Comment: I think it would still be fast. I created as jsPerf to test similar (yet different) functionality of a small array map.  Here's a link:  http://jsperf.com/bmcgin-switch-vs-if-vs-obj  I try to use this approach whenever possible.

Comment: It would be good if the replace expression was created from the map (say once only using an IIFE and closure on load) so that maintenance was reduced (only one place to udpate and maintain the list and avoiding a global variable). But understand this isn't meant to be production code. :-)